# Javascript/HTML/CSS Wheel of fortune rotate only by difference?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation, dom-manipulation

I'm building a roulette the should spin realistically and be operated by dragging the wheel and letting it go.

I've gotten 1:1 rotation down, I just need to get it to spin realistically after it's been let go.

I calculate force by measuring distance between two frames.

<s>You can view the source code here: http://www.techgoldmine.com/spinny_thing</s>

Answer (score 1):

I din't clearly understand your problem but you need to clear the interval on mouseup on document.

```
$('.mouse_trap').mousedown(function(){
        intervalvar = setInterval(monitorClicks, 24);

        /*will clear the interval and unbind the function on first mouseup on the document*/
        $(document).one('mouseup', function ()
        {
            clearInterval(intervalvar);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Oops, sorry for my previous reply. Thanks alot, you actually solved another problem.